# How to draw rectangles and assign macros to them from VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Here's what I want to do and I really don't know how to do it or if it is possible.
I have one column where some values are generated. Let's say the column number is 10.
What I want to do... if the value of a cell in that column is > 1 I want to draw a rectangle (in the next cell or close to that cell) (column 11 same row) with a macro assigned to it.
The macro will insert another row right after that one where the cell is and where the rectangle will be drawn so I have to get somehow the position of the rectangle.
Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you trying to find the last used cell, basically?

Comment: No... in one column I count the number of failed items in a process. Normally that number should be 0. So... if the number is > 1 then I want to draw a rectangle with a macro assigned. That macro will insert another row under that rectangle and cell where I'll redo that process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()
Dim c As Range

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A30")
        If c.Value > 1 Then
            AddShape c.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    Next c

End Sub


Sub AddShape(rng As Range)
    With rng.Cells(1).Parent.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, rng.Left, _
                                    rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height)
        .OnAction = "DoInsertAction"
    End With
End Sub

Sub DoInsertAction()
    Dim r As Long
    r = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
    ActiveSheet.Rows(r + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try it tomorrow... from what I see it seems what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 for cutting to the heart of the matter, if this is what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

**An alternative to shapes** would be to use a border and the double click event.

Add the code to your worksheet module and change a cell value in column 10.
Then double click the cell containing the border.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
   If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(11)) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Offset(, -1).Value > 1 And Target.Borders.Count > 0 Then
          Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert xlDown, False
          Cancel = True
        End If
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(10)) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Value > 1 And IsNumeric(Target) Then
            Target.Offset(, 1).BorderAround xlContinuous, xlMedium, xlColorIndexAutomatic
            Else
            Target.Offset(, 1).Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**If you really want to use a shape** then try something like below.

In worksheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(10)) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Value > 1 And IsNumeric(Target) Then
            AddShape Target.Offset(0, 1)
            Else
            DeleteShape Target.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In a normal module:

```
Sub AddShape(rCell As Range)
    '// Check if shape already exists
    Dim shLoop As Shape
    For Each shLoop In rCell.Parent.Shapes
        If shLoop.Type = msoShapeRectangle And shLoop.TopLeftCell = rCell Then                
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next shLoop

    With rCell.Parent.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, rCell.Left, rCell.Top, rCell.Width, rCell.Height)
        .OnAction = "ShapeClick"
    End With
End Sub

Sub DeleteShape(rCell As Range)
    Dim shLoop As Shape

    For Each shLoop In rCell.Parent.Shapes
        If shLoop.Type = msoShapeRectangle And shLoop.TopLeftCell = rCell Then
            shLoop.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub ShapeClick()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
        ActiveSheet.Rows(.TopLeftCell.Row + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an outline.  `InsertRows()` is a UDF to insert the row

```
Sub FindErrors(ByVal myrange As Range)
    Dim xCell As range
    For Each xCell In myrange
        If xCell.Value >= 1 Then
            xCell.Offset(0, 1).BorderAround xlContinuous, xlThick
            xCell.Offset(0, 1) = InsertRow(range("A13:F13"))
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Pass in a range for it to operate on.  Based on the other answer, I'm not sure the border coloring is what you are looking for, but you get the idea.

Comment: I will update the answer with actual code as we tease out more of the specifics

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here's what I do. I scan the column 10 where I have this values after every change that can result in a change of one of the cells in columns 10. If the value of one of those cells in that column is > 1 then I want to draw a rectangle right next to it same row next column with that macro assigned. I know what to write in the macro... but what I don't know is if I can get the coordinates of the rectangle somehow to know where to insert the new row

Comment: @Andrei Oh, you didn't say the rectangle and the inserted row were the same.  Sorry, I see you said column 11, so I read it wrong.  I would step through your range rowwise, if that value is greater than one, change the formatting of the adjacent cell to make your rectangle, then, step through column 11, if the formatting matches that of the rectangle, run the macro.

Comment: @Andrei it's a bit confusing also because your macro that you are running to fill in the row seems like it's independent of the one making the rectangles.

Comment: @Andrei Is this all you were asking?  Again, many apologies that I'm not getting it quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my code if helps.
Basically it draws a rectangle at the top of the pages so that you can use it as you wish to be.

```
Sub Red_Box()
    Dim BBB         As Shape
    Set BBB = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
        Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=50, Height:=50, _
        Anchor:=Selection.Range)
    With BBB
        .PictureFormat.TransparentBackground = True
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapFront
        .ZOrder (msoBringForward)
        .Select
    End With
End Sub
```