# How can I trigger a click event of an invisible control?

Tags: vba, controls, mouseclick-event, invisible

I have a background for my VBA project which contains pictures. These pictures I would like to make clickable, in the way that the click triggers a click event. I've tried adding pictureboxes, buttons and labels but I couldn't manage to make them invisible without making the click event not work (setting the Visible property to false causes this). Googling the problem, most solutions made the button look transparent by changing the color and borderstyle so the control appeared to be a part of the mono color background. I however have a specific picture that  I would like to see beneath the button.

Answer (score 1):

**To add a macro manually**

1. Right-click on the picture you want to assign the macro to.
   [image]
2. Choose `Assign Macro` from the options.
3. Assign the macro that you want to run when the picture is clicked.
   [image]

Click `OK` to finish.

**To add a macro programmatically**

If the macro is in the same workbook:

```
 ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1").OnAction = "ThisWorkbook.test"
```

If the macro is in a different workbook:

```
 ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1").OnAction = "'Book1'!test"
```

For more examples, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001933/how-to-draw-rectangles-and-assign-macros-to-them-from-vba) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685929/selection-onaction-workbooknamemacroname).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer but this is in VBA (Visual Basic) :-)